# Vaadin 8 Communication Problem, Invalid JSON from server 1|X

Tags: json, spring, vaadin8

Lately we have been getting this error a lot, I do not know whether it is related or not but the only change that comes to my mind is that we switched to AWS and we started to use Elastic Load Balancer. I do not remember getting this error before switching to AWS.

We are using Java 8, Vaadin 8, Springboot 2.0.0 on AWS EC2 with LoadBalancer.

We checked our logs but could not see anything related to this.

Comment: Was it the whole message you received? The problem is that your server's response is json, which client can't parse as it expects in a form `// for(;;);["+ realJson +"]"` [here](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/client/src/main/java/com/vaadin/client/communication/XhrConnection.java#L154). Do you have multiple servers behind load balancer? If this is the case, are you using sticky sessions?

Comment: I'm too facing the same issue. But I don't have any LoadBalancer for same. Just single instance of AWS EC2.

Comment: "We changed the Load Balancer's time out value, haven't got any error since." Could you share some details for your solution?